# how to make the username and email is Unique .. using WTFroms

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications, unique, wtforms

[wtforms](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/) is a forms validation and rendering library for python web development

but i can't find how to handle the username  and email Unique ,

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the whole page in your link and you'll find the header "Custom Validators" which shows a quick ... custom validator.

The [documentation](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/validators.html#custom-validators) has more on the topic.